# Rebuild the "run as logged in User" feature in Editions below Enterprise possible with the &fv0 Function?

Tags: lightning, urlhacking, custom-link

I want to find a way to close the GAP between the Enterprise Edition and the below ones related to the Topic "run as Logged in User" Feature on Dashboards.

So could i use the "&fv0" Function in any Way to an Dashboard in order to Pass the Logged in User ID ?

I found this thread [Custom links to generate dynamic reports in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156289/custom-links-to-generate-dynamic-reports-in-lightning/165926#165926)
and it seems possible with Reports but there  is nothing mentioned if it's possible with Dashboards.

Any help is welcome and other approaches too.. to solve this

best regards john

Comment: If you're going to do it, you'll most likely need to do it by building a lightning component. From within the component, you can run pretty much any kind of JS you want to establish the params. Security will still be an issue you'll want to address. You can leverage a server side controller to pass the logged-in user Id to the component to assure that only intended users are seeing the dashboards.